# Creating a desktop application to design Master Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, desktop-application

How would I go about creating a desktop application that would be capable of generating an ASP.NET master page, perhaps using drag and drop for the different allowed elements (image, text, video). I would take the co-ordinates and generate a master page that can be used later.

Any ideas would be great, I know the question is a bit strange and vague.

Comment: don't you find visual studio itself useful... Why not try Expression Blend then.. why code something that's already been done...

Comment: Because I want to implement it as part of my product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you're looking for in an answer.  There are several pieces to such a project.  Here's what you'd have to create:

- A text editor
- An ASP.NET parser so that you can do syntax highlighting or WYSIWYG display
- An assembly loader so you can detect which items to put in your toolbox
- A drag & drop interface
- An ASP.NET compiler so that you can test your work in a browser

You may want to look at existing frameworks as a starting point.  Eclipse is an engine for building products like yours, so you could base your project in that framework.  Scintilla is a popular library for writing text editors with syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is very strange of you to do this as there are already many tools to go about doing this.

- [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/) (is itself Self Sufficient)
- [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx) (if you need more control over Design)

Try them.

---

**Still** if you are keen about developing something that suits you **custom needs** then sure go ahead.

As the master page is similar to HTML DOM you can create tags and attributes according to the user's choice.

I suggest you take idea from Visual Studio Designer itself and develop something similar with room for your custom implementations. That way you customer's wouldn't have difficulty in switching to your Application.

As for HTML editing there are Various classes like [HTML Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.aspx) which you can use to create the DOM. Also try out some tools like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Also search for some plug-ins that you can use for making things like HTML Editor. Some has been suggested in Jacob's answer.